# How we can convert Stream Object string to Object Stream using ItextSharp in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, adobe

I'm using Java Script to convert Image to string and store in the field value. As we can see the below Javascript:

```
// Getting the Object
var oFile = this.getDataObjectContents("Test1");
//object into the string 
var cFile = util.stringFromStream(oFile, "utf-8");
// storing in the field
this.getField("Text2").value = cFile;
```

I'm reading all the field On the pdf and I'm able to get the field Value, but when I'm trying to write it, in the Server/Local machine I'm not able to  write the image. I'm using the below code.

```
byte[] br;
 // (cc.Value)// value of the field
br = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cc.Value);
//br=  imgToByteArray
byte[] pdfdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cc.Value);

Stream streamed = new MemoryStream(pdfdata);
Stream InputStream = streamed;
byte[] result;

using (var streamReaderWE = new MemoryStream())
{
    InputStream.CopyTo(streamReaderWE);
    result = streamReaderWE.ToArray();
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileNameEEEE, result);
}
```

I'm not able to return the Image

Comment: I'm not sure I understand well what you are trying to do. You are converting an image to a string, storing it in the field of a PDF file, and then want to retrieve that string and convert it back to an image, is that it ? And what do you mean by "I'm not able to return the image" ? What is the result of your code ?

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes(fileNameEEEE, result); once it will write the byte it does not create Image, initial I have convert Image to sting and then send it to Itext sharp, so i write it into the server it should be image, but it's not the image